# one table with multiple columns vs multiple tables with one column (for data in different datatypes)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to design something for the following use case:

Users can submit files with lists of key value pairs (filters) that I do not know in advance. So I cannot predefine dedicated columns for the data.

Now I am considering the following solutions:

```
table: filters
id, name, datatype

table: filter_strings
id, filters_id, value

table: filter_numbers
id, filters_id, value

table: filter_datetimes
id, filters_id, value
```

Vs:

```
table: filters
id, name, datatype, value_string, value_datetime, value_number
```

I wonder which performs better. 1 does not require a lookup over multiple tables, but I am afraid that the increased table size will increase query times (all unused datatype columns are still there and use up space)

Comment: What is your question? Presumably 'which of these is best', so then define "best"? And what are all these data? Show examples of these "files with lists" in terms of what you need to store, and what you need to get out of the database later.

Comment: When using an EAV model, I prefer the first approach.